# Slow Image Opening with xdg-open/ eog in Folder of many Files

Tags: command-line, image-viewers, xdg-open, eog

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a folder with many .png and .json files (+100k in total, no sub-folder within the folder).

When I tried to open one of its .png images with `xdg-open abc.png` or `eog abc.png`, it took 4-5 sec to open the view image window. My disk is SSD so it shouldn't have such a slow speed. Also, this problem only happen in such big folder. Both `xdg-open` and `eog` works pretty fast for images in other folders.

It's kind of annoying. Any one know the reason for such a slow speed?

Comment: Try using `eog` with `--disable-gallery` option, probably will not scan the folder for other images.

Comment: @user.dz thanks for the suggestion! but unfortunately I didnt experience any speed up after adding --disable-gallery